# Trying to do a SiteTraversal with Yodlee

Tags: rest, yodlee

I am following the quick start guide and I am able to get both the Cobrand and User token's, however when I try to make a `POST` request to `https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/searchSite`, I receive a 404 doc not found. I am able to use `wget` to download the file for `/authenticate/login` as shown below, but `wget` receives a 404.

```
zachallett@ ~/code/yodlee/sampleapp
$ wget https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/searchSite
--2013-12-09 14:48:02-- https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/searchSite
Resolving rest.developer.yodlee.com... 216.35.6.163
Connecting to rest.developer.yodlee.com|216.35.6.163|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-12-09 14:48:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.


zachallett@ ~/code/yodlee/sampleapp
$ wget https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login
--2013-12-09 14:48:16--  https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login
Resolving rest.developer.yodlee.com... 216.35.6.163
Connecting to rest.developer.yodlee.com|216.35.6.163|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: ‘login’
[ <=>             ] 16          --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-12-09 14:48:16 (1.53 MB/s) - ‘login’ saved [16]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using this from an external REST client and it works.

Here is the request

POST /services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteTraversal/searchSite HTTP/1.1
Host: rest.developer.yodlee.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

cobSessionToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&userSessionToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&siteSearchString=dag